# Replacing null values with blanks using proc stdize

Tags: replace, sas, proc

I am working with data in SAS environment. I'm trying to replace missing values with blanks for an entire table. Missing values can be found in columns that are both character and numeric.

I tried using the following:

> `RSUBMIT; proc stdize data=Final_note out=final_note_blanks reponly missing=''; run; quit; ENDRSUBMIT;`
> but since some of the columns are operating on numeric data types, this won't work because '' is a character. Below is the error message I received:

Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a numeric constant, a datetime constant, ABW, AGK, AHUBER, AWAVE, EUCLEN, IQR, LEAST, MAD, MAXABS, MEAN, MEDIAN, MIDRANGE, RANGE, SPACING, STD, SUM, USTD. The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored

Comment: SAS missing values for character values are represented by blanks. Can you clarify with data what you're looking to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot replace a missing numeric value with a blank. This can only be done with character values. However, you can represent missing values as blank for reporting purposes.

```
options missing = '';
```

This only changes the way it is presented. SAS still sees it as a missing numeric value.

[image]